# F# constructor syntax

Tags: f#

when using .net classes, there are cases when we don't need parenthesis to pass a single parameter like

```
let foo = DirectoryInfo "boo"
```

but something a little more complicated using a single parameter, we do need parenthesis...
does anyone know the parsing rules when this is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In F#, all functions take a single parameter. Now this may be a little confusing at first, because you can have a function which appears to take more than one parameter, but you're actually passing a single parameter that is a tuple.

Here's a simple example of constructors that appear like they take more than 1 parameter:

```
let foo = DirectoryInfo "boo" //passing 1 argument
let foo2 = DirectoryInfo ("boo") //passing 1 argument that is a tuple
let foo3 = StringBuilder ("blah", 100) //passing 1 argument again
let foo4 = StringBuilder "blah" 100 //does not compile
```

For more info about this style, check out [Tuples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx).

Now, there also is another slightly different method of making it seem like a function takes more than 1 argument. This is called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), which you will see more often when dealing only with F# code.  Here's a [quick example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/198973-f%23-an-introduction-to-currying/) of this.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am aware of the tuple in parenthesis, but i saw that in some cases .net classes need to have their parameters in parenthesis, even though its a single parameter, and now i think it's when the object is IDisposable and we need to use the new operator. so, something like new SomeDisposable (foo) needs parenthesis

Comment: I'm not sure that's accurate. For example, with `FileSystemWatcher` this compiles fine:
`let watcher = new FileSystemWatcher "blah"`

Comment: It may be worth noting that many F# code samples always use parentheses when invoking a class constructor. While this is required for multi-parameter class constructors, doing so in the singular makes class constructor calls look like the typical form of discriminated union constructor calls, which are common across most ML-family languages.

Comment: I always use parens, even for single-param constructors, just for consistency. No need to complicate code with special cases when they can be avoided.